Energy gained by relativistic falling object
Consider a gravitating body and a test mass. The test mass has purely radial inward velocity very close to c (with respect to observers at infinity who consider the gravitating body stationary) and some small rest mass m. I'm interested in calculating the rate of change (WRT clocks of those distant observers) of the kinetic energy of this test mass (measured as energy released when the mass hits something "still" such as the surface of the attractor). If it matters for approximation reasons, the gravity of the attractor may be considered weak (within an OOM of earth gravity) at the distance where the experiment is conducted.
Since the falling mass has $v\approx c$, its velocity will not appreciably increase as it falls, so my first instinct was to say that its power was simply $mgc$ by a simple potential energy argument. However, I don't know if this is applicable, since the mass has significant kinetic energy, which may increase the "force" on it. I could calculate it using the relativistic mass $E/c^2$, but if I'm applying relativistic effects to a falling object I think I should be using GR. Unfortunately, I don't know much at all about GR, and all the questions about falling objects I could find are about energy contributions to black holes, which aren't what I care about.

For clarity: are you considering the force of gravity to increase/change over time?

controlgroup No, I'm considering the instantaneous rate of change as a function of some fixed gravitational acceleration g. If I need to calculate energy gained over some significant fall, I can integrate with g as a function of t, but that's a different question.

A projectile travelling near c traverses ~47 Earth radii per second, so g changes pretty quickly. OTOH, Earth escape speed is ~11 km/s, which is negligible compared to c. So in the Earth frame, the potential energy of your projectile is negligible compared to its kinetic energy.

I could be a truly vast distance away from a supermassive black hole, if you like, but in any case this question simply assumes constant gravity.

Alright then, see my addendum.

If you are considering the instantaneous rate of change of the object's kinetic energy at any given time when the force on it due to (approximately Newtonian) gravity is $F$, note that $F=\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}$, and then note that
$$E_\text{total}^2=p^2c^2+m^2c^4$$
from the energy-momentum relation, for rest mass $m$ and lightspeed $c$. Subtracting the rest energy from this gives the kinetic energy:
$$E_\text{kinetic}=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}-mc^2=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{p^2}{m^2c^2}}}-mc^2=(\gamma-1)mc^2.$$
The simplification I did is common. Then, differentiate with respect to time. This at least seems correct to me; it's possible there's a mistake but this seems like the simplest way to do what you're trying to do. Plugging this expression (probably the second, the one with the explicit Lorentz factor) into Wolfram|Alpha would certainly give a correct answer, but the process of differentiating w.r.t. $t$ seems easy enough to me, holding every variable except $p$ constant and knowing $F=\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}$.

A note: when calculating $F=G\frac{Mm}{r^2}$ (with the gravitating body’s mass $M$ and the falling body’s mass $m$), you use the objects’ rest mass $m_0$ to calculate force. Why? Well, it wouldn’t make sense if objects’ relativistic mass were used.
Consider a more mundane scenario: me jumping up and then falling back to Earth. If we use the relativistic mass to calculate the gravitational force I put on the Earth, what frame of reference do we use? There exists a valid inertial frame of reference where my rest mass is multiplied by $10^100$, and one in which it is simply my rest mass. Additionally, the Earth’s mass doesn’t scale by the same factor  - since it and I have different velocities and $\gamma$ is not linear with velocity - so the Earth would appear to experience different gravitational forces exerted by me depending on the reference frame chosen. That goes against the primary postulate of relativity, which is that physics is the same in all frames. Worse yet, I might seem to undergo gravitational collapse into a black hole in some specific frames but not other - that doesn’t make sense! A black hole in one frame, a black hole in every other frame.
Instead, we use the rest mass. Using the rest mass, the apparent force I put on the Earth is the same in all inertial reference frames (after accounting for time dilation). This is also motivated by the Schwarzschild solution being exactly valid in the rest frame of the body - it is the rest mass that is $M$ in the metric.

This is similar to what I did to get the mgc value for power, and it has the same potential problem: When you calculate force, you have to do it as mg. (or GMm/r2, which reduces to the same thing). But I don't know if, for a fast-moving body, the m in question should be rest mass (m0) or adjusted relativistic mass ym0.

A force exerts gravitational force equal to its rest mass, so simply $m_0$ should work there. (To understand why, consider that if it varied with the relativistic mass instead, then there would be frames in which any object should appear to be a black hole, which means that it should be a black hole everywhere, which is not observed, citation: the earth is not a black hole).

controlgroup That's 90% of the answer I was looking for right there, if you edit that into into your answer explicitly I'll accept it.

The KE is:
$$ T = E - mc^2 = (\gamma-1)\times mc^2 $$
The potential energy is:
$$ U = G\frac{Mm} r $$
In terms of the Schwarzschild radius:
$$ r_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2} $$
That is:
$$ U = \frac 1 2 \frac {r_s} r \times mc^2$$
The ratio is:
$$ \frac T U =2\frac{(\gamma-1)}{r_s/r} $$
So when you talk about $\gamma \gg 1$, the gravity doesn't matter until the object is compact. Even a white dwarf has that ratio around $r_s/r \approx 1/1000$, so if it's not a neutron start: forget about it.
Also: in high gravity, the potential energy picks up higher order terms:
$$ U = \frac{GMm}r\Big(1 + a_2\big(\frac{r_s} r
\big)^2 + \cdots\Big) $$
while, I think, diverges logarithmically as $r_s/r \rightarrow 1$.

I'm not sure why I would calculate the potential U like this to begin with, much less the ratio T/U. I was trying to calculate the power of the object, aka rate of change of kinetic energy

the point is gravity irrelevant, but why not: $dU/dr \cdot dr/dt \approx GMmc/r^2$.
